# Use javascript library inside of TypeScript React web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, jointjs

I'm trying to put a [graphical editor](http://www.jointjs.com/) into a React component but the project is setup on **TypeScript**.

There are no updated bindings for JointJS, thats why I tried the following: Render the code coming from JointJS into a React component in a .jsx file

File: joint-editor.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'
import joint from 'jointjs'

export default class JointEditor extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

      //JointJS code using jQuery

      graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);

      return (<div id="myholder"></div>)
  }

}
```

And then **importing** this component into another component in a .tsx file

File editor.tsx

```
import React = require('react')
import Header = require("./../Header/header")
import JointEditor = require('./joint-editor')

class DemoProps {
    public name: string;
    public age: string;
}

export class Editor extends React.Component<DemoProps, {}> {
    private foo: number;

    constructor(props: DemoProps) {
        super(props);
        this.foo = 42;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header.Header/>
                <JointEditor/>
                Hello {this.props.name}, you are {this.props.age} years old
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This gets bundled by webpack and transpiled by Babel (jsx file) and TypeScript (tsx)

Now 2 problems arise:

1. ERROR in .../editor.tsx
   (3,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module './joint-editor'.
2. I'm pretty sure there will be problems with JointJS using jQuery inside of the render() method of React? Do you know of any samples where jQuery is used successfully inside of a React component?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack=require('webpack');
module.exports={
    entry: ['./src/main.tsx'],
    output: {
        path: './target',
        publicPath: "/assets/",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['',  '.jsx','.ts', '.js', '.tsx',]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                loader: 'react-hot!ts-loader'
            },{
                test:/\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader:"react-hot!babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test:/\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader:"babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: the extension of your `joint-editor` is `.jsx`, which is an extension node/ts [do not resolve by default](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules).

Comment: @DanPantry yes this is why I configured webpack to use BabelJS as a loader when JSX files are found.

Comment: thats fine, but typescript isn't going to recognise that (most likely)

Comment: okay but shouldn't it render anyways because everything is packed in a bundle.js?

Comment: I'm more addressing your first error - `editor.tsx` isn't going to be able to 'find' `joint-editor` because of its extension. You need to set `resolve.extensions` in your webpack config to include `.tsx` and `.jsx`

Comment: That's what I'm doing, see my updated answer @DanPantry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93829/discussion-between-shady-and-dan-pantry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- `import JointEditor from './joint-editor'`

2- Move your jQuery code to the `componentDidMount()` method (the DOM is rendered)

```
const div = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
```

is the `HTMLDivElement` which is the root of your React Element

Comment: Couldn't get it to work with a jsx file but I found working bindings for JointJS on DefinitelyTyped and the approach via componentDidMount works well. Thanks.